# Can't create() nested relationship with DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is the first time I'm working with DRF.

My models:

```
class ServiceCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=24)

class Service(models.Model):
    service = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    category = models.ForeignKey('ServiceCategory')
```

Their serializers:

```
class ServiceCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ServiceCategory
        fields = ('id', 'category')

class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = ServiceCategorySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = ('service', 'category')

    def create(self, data):
        return Service.objects.create(**data)
```

And the view:

```
elif request.method == 'POST':
    serializer = ServiceSerializer(data=request.data)

    print(serializer.initial_data) # To debug the contents of the request

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Initially, before I added the nested category to the ServiceSerializer, I had no problem creating new Services. The `print(serializer.initial_data)` outputs `<QueryDict: {'category': ['1'], 'service': ['EC2']}>` so obviously I'm supplying the category to the request but I'm getting `"category" : ["This field is required"]` errors.

So I'm thinking the problem might be with my `create(self, data)` method in the ServiceSerializer but I'm unable to put a finger on what exactly is wrong with it.

What have I missed?

**UPDATE**

Without the ServiceCategorySerializer in the ServiceSerializer, and the view being:

```
elif request.method == 'POST':
    serializer = ServiceSerializer(data=request.data)

    print(serializer.initial_data) # for debugging

    if serializer.is_valid():
        print(serializer.data) # for debugging
```

`serializer.initial_data` returns `<QueryDict: {'category': ['1'], 'service': ['EC2']}>`
and
`serializer.data` returns `{'service': 'EC2', 'category': 1}` so I assume the contents of `serializer.data` are what will get passed to the `create()` method of the ServiceSerializer. By itself, it works, but when I include the ServiceCategorySerializer inside it, the POST doesn't go through and I get the same annoying `"category" : ["This field is required"]`

I've been stuck with this for over 6 hours now. What is going on???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a full working example - of what you wanna achieve - using just information that I found in this thread:

Models:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models


class ServiceCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=24)


class Service(models.Model):
    service = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    category = models.ForeignKey('ServiceCategory')
```

Serializers:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from nestedd.models import ServiceCategory, Service


class ServiceCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ServiceCategory
        fields = ('id', 'category')


class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = ServiceCategorySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = ('service', 'category')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        category_data = validated_data.pop('category')
        # 'created' will be True if no existing category matches
        category, created = ServiceCategory.objects.get_or_create(**category_data)
        return Service.objects.create(category=category, **validated_data)
```

Views:

```
# Create your views here.
from rest_framework import viewsets

from nestedd.models import Service
from nestedd.serializers import ServiceSerializer


class ServiceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Service.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ServiceSerializer
```

urls:

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from nestedd.views import ServiceViewSet

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'nested', ServiceViewSet, base_name='service')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

app urls:

```
url(r'^api/v2/', include('nestedd.urls')),
```

And this how my postman look likes:

[image: Postman request]

**THE PROBLEM - POST DATA FORMAT**

Probably you made a wrong POST query - if you want to use nested serializer, like this:

```
category = ServiceCategorySerializer()
```

In some other serializer, you must know that first field name is attached to the parent serializer, eg.:

```
{
     "service_name": "test",
     "category": ...
}
```

And what should be placed in category field? Well - an object, because you tell that this field is another serializer, if object then:

```
{
    "service_name": "test",
    "category": {
        "category": "some_category"
    }
}
```

And in this object you specify the fields for the model which is described by inner serializer, so basically, when you pass only the "id" -> it obvious that ServiceCategory cannot be created, beacause the category field on model ServiceCategory - is required.

**ANOTHER NOTE: EXISITING VS. NON EXISITNG CATEGORY**

You will have problems with handling existing/non-existing category;
Basically you should make category field unique on ServiceCategory, and in post on ServiceViewSet - check if category exists (if so take it and assign to the Service object - if no - create a category) - in this scenario you will not need to pass category id each time. And handle it when id - does not exists.

Answer (score 1):

When POSTing a service, the `category` field must contain a PK, i.e. an integer. Your `category` field in `serializer.initial_data` contains a list with a string.

BTW1: your `service` field also has a list when your model expects a string (`CharField`). This might also be a problem.

BTW2: No need to override your serializer's `create` in your case.

Comment: Yeah. But `serializer.initial_data` and `serializer.validated_data` are different. For example, in another serializer, `serializer.initial_data` outputs `<QueryDict: {'location': ['North Virginia'], 'region': ['us-east-1']}>` while `serializer.validated_data` for the same outputs `OrderedDict([('region', 'us-east-1'), ('location', 'North Virginia')])`

Comment: Well, in this second example, there is indeed no `category`, while your model states that every `Service` must have a category (no explicit `null=True` in your `ForeignKey`). This is why your serializer complains when `.is_valid()` is called.

Comment: My bad. This is another serializer, specifically a RegionSerializer which has absolutely no relationship whatsoever with the ServiceSerializer. I just used it to point out that in general, `serializer.initial_data` contains lists but `serializer.validated_data` does not.

Comment: And BTW, the ServiceCategory already exists. I have a ServiceCategory with `id = 1` already in the database.

Comment: I see. I would say that the problem then is only that '1' is a string but it expects an integer, although from my experience the error wouldn't be `"This field is required"`.

Comment: But ideally, the '1' **WILL** be an integer without me having to format it. Check out the update I've made to the question.

Comment: @lucasnadalutti you are totally wrong here: category for sure not MUST contains PK -> it depends how things are implemented. This is first. And Second - you should get more familiar with how QueryDict displays its content:

>>> d = QueryDict(mutable=True)
>>> d['category'] = 1
>>> d
<QueryDict: {u'category': [1]}>
>>> d['category'] = 2
>>> d
<QueryDict: {u'category': [2]}>
>>> d['category']
2
>>>

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writing-create-methods-for-nested-representations), you should implement the `create()` method in a slightly different way, saving the category first if it doesn't exist yet, and then passing it to the `Service.objects.create()` function, like this (*untested*):

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    category_data = validated_data.pop('category')
    # 'created' will be True if no existing category matches
    category, created = ServiceCategory.objects.get_or_create(**category_data)
    return Service.objects.create(category=category, **validated_data)
```

Comment: I've actually copy pasted this as is and it doesn't work. I tried everything recommended by the docs with no success. The category I'm passing actually exists and I want it to go through before handling the case where a category doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I've updated the code. It was ServiceCategory, not Category. Anyway, please, include error messages instead of just saying "it doesnt work".

Comment: Oh, I've changed the code accordingly. And the error message is still the same as I mentioned in my question: `"category" : ["This field is required"]`