# Serializer works in the Django shell but fails in the view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have those models:

```
class ServiceCategory(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'service_categories'

    category = models.CharField(max_length=24)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category


class Service(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'services'

    service = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    category = models.ForeignKey('ServiceCategory')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.service
```

And their serializers:

```
class ServiceCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ServiceCategory
        fields = ('id', 'category')

class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = ServiceCategorySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = ('id', 'service', 'category')
```

After this setup, [I quickly bumped into a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40770154/cant-create-nested-relationship-with-drf) creating a new `Service` via its associated `ServiceSerializer`: I have to also pass a complete `ServiceCategory` with all its fields even though I only need its `id`. The `ServiceCategory` above looks simple enough but that's hardly the case since I've omitted a lot of its other fields for brevity.

So passing the complete attributes of a `ServiceCategory` into a form on the front end seemed terribly inefficient to me so I tried another approach:

```
class UpsertServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.IntegerField() # not ServiceCategorySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = ('service', 'category')

    def create(self, data):
        c = ServiceCategory.objects.get(pk=data['category'])
        return Service.objects.create(service=data['service'], category=c)
```

My intention is to use `UpsertServiceSerializer` for creates and updates, with `ServiceSerializer` now being used for reads. `UpsertServiceSerializer` worked without a problem in the Django shell — the create goes through with me having to pass just the `id` of the `ServiceCategory` instead of all its attributes and a new `Service` object is indeed added to the database — but when I make a `POST` request via Postman, I get this error:

```
TypeError at /services 
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'ServiceCategory'
```

So I tried a new version of `UpsertServiceSerializer`:

```
class UpsertServiceSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    service = serializers.CharField()
    category = serializers.IntegerField()

    def create(self, data):
        c = ServiceCategory.objects.get(pk=data['category'])
        return Service.objects.create(service=data['service'], category=c)
```

Notice that in the new version, I'm subclassing `serializers.Serializer` instead of `serializers.ModelSerializer`, and there's no `class Meta` inside it. This version is no different, it also passes in the Django shell but fails in the view with the same TypeError.

Here's the view:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def services(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        services = Service.objects.all()
        serializer = ServiceSerializer(services, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = UpsertServiceSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common problem with understanding about how related fields work in serializer. `ForeignKey` by default use `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` so you don't need an `IntegerField`, even though you don't need overriding `create` method.

```
class UpsertServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = ('service', 'category')
```

Passing `pk` for category will just work. In the case when you need special layout for `category` model not a plain `pk`, you could write you own `to_representation` method.

```
 class UpsertServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     ...
     def to_representation(self, instance):
         representation = super(UpsertServiceSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
         representation['category'] = ServiceCategorySerializer(instance.category).data
         return representation
```

Comment: Thanks. Very valuable information. Accepted and upvoted.